# how many characters can be put in "Data"text field of media-internal-text item descriptor

Tags: atg

I am creating a repository item of media-internal-text item descriptor type.I have put some text in "data" field in BCC. I want to know how many characters can be put in  "Data"field of media-internal-text item descriptor in atg bcc? If characters are not sufficient how to increase the character size limit?

Answer (score 0):

The `DCS_MEDIA_TXT` table holds the `DATA` field you refer to. The definition of this column is a `CLOB` (for an Oracle Database) of which the size limit is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm) which should indicate that it, by its nature, can store a large number of characters.